# How to find residue of the pole in this two variables complex function at y = 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

One has function of two complex variables $f(x, y) = \frac{x^y}{y^2}$. From some simple calculations from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity we get $\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{x^y}{y^2}= \tilde{\infty}$ or alternatively if we do not want to use complex limit complexity: $\lim_{y\rightarrow0}|\frac{x^y}{y^2}|= \infty$ (as I understand only in the first case we have complex limit, i.e. in all complex directions). The inverse complex limit is simpler:  $\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{y^2}{x^y}= 0$.

So that means for any $x$ we have a pole at $y=0$. Now the problem is I want to find the residue but all naive formulas require one to have just 1 variable, though I can do contour integration around $y = 0$ (that gives residue 0 and multiplicity 2 for all values), or I can do Laurent expansion, that gives residue $ 2 iπ \ln(x)$. Looks like last result is correct, can someone confirm?

Comment: What is $\tilde{\infty}$?

Comment: Complex limit (in all directions, even complex) is only defined on a Riemann sphere, which has no plus infinity or minus infinity. It has only complex infinity. That is standard symbol in complex analysis.

Comment: Okay, $\tilde{\infty}$ is the point at infinity.  Understood.  Sorry, haven't seen this (standard) symbol.  Any sources you could point to that use this notation?

Comment: I prefer that to $\infty_\mathbb{C}$ and actually this will be a third Riemann sphere that is $f(x, y)$. Wolfram uses it.

Comment: use the residue formula which gives it as the derivative (in $y$) of $x^y$ at $y=0$ and that is $\log x$ where $\log x$ is the same used in the definition of $x^y$

Comment: @Conrad I would need a proof. Even if it is treating it as parameter.

Comment: Standard formula (or just expand $x^y$ in Taylor series in $y$ so it is $1+y\log x +...$)

Comment: A far as your calculations here are concerned, this is just a function of $y$, not a two-variable function. You are treating $x$ as a constant, not a variable. You may vary $x$ elsewhere in what you are doing, but you are not doing so in calculating this residue. Those "naive formulas" are completely applicable.